# A Solidity Linearization Puzzle

Tags: solidity, remix, inheritance

I was playing in [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) just to concretize my understanding of Solidity linearization, and got a result I didn't expect and can't rationalize. Why does `AC_BA.go()` return `3`?

(Please scroll to the bottom of the code below.)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract A {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
        out = 1;
    }
}
contract B {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
        out = 2;
    }
}
contract C {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
        out = 3;
    }
}

// returns 2 as expected
contract AB is A, B {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
       out = super.go();
    }
}

// returns 1 as expected
contract BA is B, A {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
       out = super.go();
    }
}

// returns 3 as expected
contract AC is A, C {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
       out = super.go();
    }
}

// refuses to compile, can't linearize, ok
//
// contact AC_A is AC, A {
//     function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
//       out = super.go();
//    }
// }

// compiles, returns 2, from AB
contract AC_AB is AC, AB {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
       out = super.go();
    }
}

// compiles, returns 3, why???
contract AC_BA is AC, BA {
    function go() public pure returns (uint out) {
       out = super.go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing the notation from [C3 linearization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization), and keeping in mind that Solidity [reverses the typical ordering](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization) ("You have to list the direct base contracts in the order from 'most base-like' to 'most derived'. Note that this order is different from the one used in Python."):

```
L(AC) := [AC] + merge(L(C), L(A), [C, A])
       = [AC] + merge([C], [A], [C, A])
       = [AC, C] + merge([A], [A])
       = [AC, C, A]

L(BA) := [BA] + merge(L(A), L(B), [A, B])
       = [BA] + merge([A], [B], [A, B])
       = [BA, A] + merge([B], [B])
       = [BA, A, B]

L(AC_BA) := [AC_BA] + merge(L(BA), L(AC), [BA, AC])
          = [AC_BA] + merge([BA, A, B], [AC, C, A], [BA, AC])
          = [AC_BA, BA] + merge([A, B], [AC, C, A], [AC])
          = [AC_BA, BA, AC] + merge([A, B], [C, A])
          = [AC_BA, BA, AC, C] + merge([A, B], [A])
          = [AC_BA, BA, AC, C, A] + merge([B])
          = [AC_BA, BA, AC, C, A, B]
```

So calling `AC_BA.go()` ends up calling `C.go()`, which returns 3. I don't have an intuitive explanation for you; this is just the behavior of the C3 linearization algorithm, which Solidity follows.

**EDIT**

The Solidity compiler can export an AST which includes the linearization of base contracts. A little Python can convert it into a readable form:

```
import json
import sys

symbol_map = {}

for source in json.load(sys.stdin)['sources'].values():
    for symbol, ids in source['AST']['attributes']['exportedSymbols'].items():
        for id in ids:
            symbol_map[id] = symbol

    for child in source['AST']['children']:
        attributes = child['attributes']
        if attributes.get('contractKind', None) == 'contract':
            print('{}: {}'.format(attributes['name'], ' -> '.join(symbol_map[id] for id in attributes['linearizedBaseContracts'])))
```

How to run it:

```
solc --combined-json ast test.sol | python3 linearization.py
```

Output:

```
A: A
B: B
C: C
AB: AB -> B -> A
BA: BA -> A -> B
AC: AC -> C -> A
AC_AB: AC_AB -> AB -> B -> AC -> C -> A
AC_BA: AC_BA -> BA -> AC -> C -> A -> B
```

When you call `AC_BA.go()`, that calls `BA.go()`, which in turn calls `AC.go()` and finally `C.go()` (returning 3).

**EDIT 2**

[Surya](https://github.com/ConsenSys/surya) is a handy tool that will show contract inheritance in linearized order.

```
$ surya dependencies AC_BA test.sol
AC_BA
  ↖ BA
  ↖ AC
  ↖ C
  ↖ A
  ↖ B
```

Comment: Given the [potential costs of misunderstanding the linearization of ones contracts](https://pdaian.com/blog/solidity-anti-patterns-fun-with-inheritance-dag-abuse/), and the not-so-intuitive outcomes, it'd be nice if solc emitted the linearization it settles upon. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: Edited my answer. The first part was actually wrong (forgot that Solidity reverses the typical order of base classes), and I added the second part which shows how to get the Solidity compiler to tell you the linearization.

Comment: Thanks! (That makes a lot more sense, I was a bit confused about the prior ordering, but thought it was on me to puzzle that out.) I'll try Surya.